# json_encode php 5.5 vs 5.3 not playing nice with js

Tags: javascript, php, expressionengine

Here is the issue:

`$locArr` is a huge array

Then to pull that information into js I use

```
var oLocations = <?= json_encode($locArr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>;
```

code produced by `oLocations = json_encode($locArr);`

```
var oLocations = $.parseJSON( ,"LastDataBuild":"","Drop24Hour":"NO","Pickup24Hour":"NO","MileageUnit":"MI","AirportIndicator":"0",...
```

Notice the first comma, this throws

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

if I wrap everything in quotes so that it evaluates to a string I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I've tried json_encoding in and outside of the javascript, nothings seems to work.

The hardest part about all of this is that at PHP 5.5 I can use:

`json_encode($locArr, JSON_PRETTY_TEXT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );`

and everything works okay. The console will output a nice OBJECT instead of a string, without any errors.

Has anyone else experienced this or do you have any ideas of other things I can try?

Below is the current state of my code (I have been interchangeably adding/removing a few lines of code. at a time):

Declaring the var in PHP:

```
    $oLocations = json_encode($locArr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

JS trying to use the array:

```
var oLocations = JSON.parse(<?= $oLocations ; ?>);
        // while(oLocations.charAt(0) !== '"'){
        //  oLocations = oLocations.substr(1);
        // };
        // oLocations = '{' + oLocations;
        // oLocations = $.parseJSON(oLocations);
        // oLocations = JSON.parse(oLocations);
        // console.log(oLocations);
        // oLocations = $.parseJSON(oLocations);
```

For this example JS threw this `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o "` and this is the code its referencing:

```
var oLocations = $.parseJSON([{"RentalLocationID":"KBR","RentalLocationStatus":"Active","RentalLocationType":"Corporate","RentalLocationName":"KBR HOURS M-F 730-6 SAT 9-1 SUN 10-2","AddressLine1":"8555 JOHN CARPENTER FWY","AddressLine2":"","Latitude":"0","Longitude":"0","AddressCity":"DALLAS","AddressState":"TX","AddressStateName":"TEXAS","AddressZipCode":"75247","AddressCountry":"US","AddressCountryName":"UNITED STATES","PhoneNumber":"214-630-6555","AltPhoneNumber":"","FAXNumber":"","ConfirmMessage":["","","",""], ...
```

Comment: Your statement `<? json_encode($locArr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>` is missing an `echo`. Without it, the JSON string is generated, but not used at all.

Comment: I'm sorry misread that, that is a typo. Fixing now.

Comment: You don't need to pass it through JSON.parse. You can just do `var oLocations = <?= echo $oLocations; ?>;

Comment: I've tried both ways, parsing the variable in JS and encoding in php and every combination inbetween. Is it possible that my array is too large to be encoded as a JSON?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON you're getting from `json_encode($locArr, JSON_PRETTY_TEXT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );` or the value of $locArr (or both)?

Comment: The JSON_PRETTY_TEXT adds a break after each comma. Unfortunately I cannot provide the actual array. It holds contains some sensative information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not inside of my PHP or JS. It was inside of Expressionengine. It was picking up the "{" and trying to interpret it using EE codes. In the end we ended up using a Pretty Print alternative function that added breaks to each line pairing of key and value.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with json_encode when the array is nested 127+ levels deep.

If you're really dealing with a huge array, that's probably what it is.

https://www.php.net/json_decode#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues

Edit: Also weird that you aren't echoing the initial json_encode out and that it's giving you results.

Comment: Isn't json_decode used for converting JSON back to php variables? I'm starting with a php array and need to converted TO JSON for JS.